# See CPU use history as a graph in a Linux shell

Tags: linux, command-line, system-monitor

I am looking for a free program that can display the CPU use history as a graph in a Linux shell, as bmon (`sudo apt-get install -y bmon`) can do network use per network interface.

[image]

or like Microsoft Windows's resource monitor can display:

[image]

`top` and `htop` only display the current CPU use.

---

[sar (System Activity Report)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sar_(Unix)) (system monitor command used to report on various system loads, including CPU activity, memory/paging, device load, network. Linux distributions provide sar through the sysstat package.) is nice (`sudo apt-get install -y systat`) but I'd prefer to have a graph:

[image]

Same for [mpstats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpstat) (`sudo apt-get install -y systat`), nice but no graph:

[image]

Ideally, the program would have an option to CPU use history *per process*. (i.e. we could choose the process ID to display)

Comment: Does `tload` (provided by the `procps` package in Debian/Ubuntu) count?

Comment: @Seth Thanks, it looks super primitive but yes :) You're welcome to post it as answer!

Answer (score 46):

You can use [s-tui](https://github.com/amanusk/s-tui):

- free and open source (GNU General Public License v2.0, written in Python)
- allows to monitor CPU temperature, frequency, power and utilization in a graphical way from the terminal:

[image]

To install:

```
pip install s-tui
```

Comment: i love this one

Answer (score 22):

`tload` (from the `procps` package on Debian and Ubuntu) provides a basic system load graph:

[image]

You can set the scale with `-s` and the delay (in seconds) with `-d`.

[Symbols](https://serverfault.com/q/370447/126950):

- `*` represents the level of [load average],(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29).
- `-`  defines the unities of load,
- `=` substitutes the "-" when the bar passes the line that marks the unit of the graph.

Annotated example:

```
------------------------------------- load 3

                     *  
                     **
--------------------====------------- load 2
    **             ******   **
   ******         *************
  *********       **************
--=========-------==============----- load 1
*************************************
*************************************
*************************************
************************************* load 0
```

`sudo apt-get install -y procps`

Answer (score 11):

[**`ttyload`**](http://www.daveltd.com/src/util/ttyload/) has a *Debian* package available.

> [image: Screenshot of ttyload]

([More screenshots](http://www.daveltd.com/src/util/ttyload/screenshots.html))

**`ttyload`** shows an asterix graph of CPU usage averages taken 1 minute at a time in red, 5 minutes at a time in green, and 15 minutes at a time in blue -- all three on one grid.  The bigger time slices help put momentary spikes in better perspective.

Comment: `sudo apt -y install ttyload` for those lazy people

Comment: last updated Oct 2013