# See GPU use history as a graph in a Linux shell

Tags: linux, command-line, gpu-monitor

I am looking for a program that can display the GPU use history as a graph in a Linux shell, as bmon (`sudo apt-get install -y bmon`) can do network use per network interface or `tload` can do for [CPU use](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/24921/903).

It should work with Nvidia cards used with CUDA.

---

On Windows 8, one can for example use [Process Explorer](http://mcakins.com/2012/05/22/capturing-gpu-usage-on-windows-8/):

[image: process explorer GPU usage graph]